# Is BigQuery a bad fit for general purpose ops?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking to use bigquery as a scalable SQL database where transactions or modify/delete ops are not needed. Instead to modify or delete I'm looking to create new time based versions of the records so that I can audit any change and also roll-back(if I need to). bigquery seems advertised only for analytics/"big data" but never as general purpose database without modify/transactions. Is it wrong to use it that way? Am I missing something?

Comment: research more to ask a conctete question. look at pricing and how queries work in bigquery. otherwise too broad.